# mysqli_stmt::get_result() call to undifined

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am changing all my scripts to prepared statements with mysqli and I have a problem. I get this error when I use `get_result()` and I don't know why. My php version is 5.3.

Here is the code I use:

```
$user=$_GET['user'];
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("select * from `users` where id= ? and stare!=1"); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

//do something

}
```

Error:

```
Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/websoft/public_html/twingoo/engine/app/profil_edit.php on line 13
```

Comment: check if mysqlnd is installed ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php#105802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem recently.

You need to make sure that the `mysqlnd` extension is installed for that particular part of `mysqli` to work.

Depending on if you are using Windows or Linux (and what flavor of either) will determine how this is done.

In CentOS, it is pretty straight-forward :

```
yum install php-mysqlnd
```

And to confirm it is installed, you can create a php page with the following :

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then  look for `mysqlnd` or `native`

You can also validate it is installed by

```
php -m | grep mysqlnd
```

OR

```
php -i | grep mysqlnd
```

Comment: I used phpinfo() and seems there is not mysqldn, the only thing i found is --enable-gd-native-ttf, i'm gna contact my hosting service to install mysqldn, thnx :)

Comment: Exact extension is  `mysqlnd` (MySQl Native Driver for PHP)